# Group of 100 user and 100 products sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql table with userid, productid and reviewScore with more than 10 million records. We can imagine userid and productid combination is unique. I need to find matrix of 100 * 100 of userid and product id with their review score.

Sample Input Table - Here the first problem is need to identify common 100 userid and product combination out of 10 million rows for which have reviews and than pivot that to matrix form based .

The productId will form dynamic pivot elements.

Input
Table1

```
UserID  ProductId   ReviewScore
User1   Product1    1
User1   Product2    2
User1   Product3    1
User1   Product4    3
User1   Product5    5
User2   Product1    3
User2   Product2    4
User2   Product3    5
User2   Product4    2
User2   Product5    5
User3   Product1    1
User3   Product2    3
User3   Product3    5
User3   Product4    3
User3   Product5    4
User4   Product1    3
User4   Product2    3
User4   Product3    3
User4   Product4    4
User4   Product5    4
User5   Product1    2
User5   Product2    2
User5   Product3    2
User5   Product4    3
User5   Product5    3
```

Output which I require.

```
UserId  Product1    Product2    Product3    Product4    Product5
User1   1            2           1           3             5
User2   3            4           5           2             5
User3   1            3          5            3             4
User4   3            3           3           4             4
User5   2            2           2           3              2
```

Here the output should be 100* 100 usesrid * product id with review score as values. The idea is to have minimum sparse or 0 values.

I have to write the same query in sql server.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which 100 users should be in result? How do you choose them from 10mln rows?

Comment: We can choose top 100 common userId which have given review scores for common 100 product.

Comment: @giorgi 100 userids who have given review scores for atleast common 100 products. If count is more than we can get top 100.

Comment: Do you already have table result with 10000 rows like those 25 rows in test data? Do you want just final pivoting query or you want query that will filter those 100 top users with pivoting?

Comment: Thanks Giorgi.. Actually I am finding difficult writing both the queries. First I need that 10000 queries of 100 * 100 userid  * product id. I tried pivoting but wasnt able to get that 100 rows  correctly in same query. So first I need query for 100 common userid and than pivot them on 100 products with their review in matrix form. The final output is the one which i mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pivote` within `dynamic sql`:

```
DECLARE @prods AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @prods = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ProductId) 
                    from tab
                    --where limit the products here
                    group by ProductId
                    order by ProductId
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT * from 
             (
                select UserID, ProductId, ReviewScore
                from tab --here also you can limit the products and users by where clause
             ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(ReviewScore)
                for ProductId in (' + @prods + ')
            ) p '

EXECUTE(@query)
```

the [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8a30b/7)

Comment: Thanks Farheg. I ran this query and its still running since last 5 min. I have over 60 million records in the table so I need to narrow that first. Here your this block STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ProductId) 
                    from tab
                    group by ProductId
                    order by ProductId
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
is taking lot of time. Your approach is right. I will mark the answer once i test it.

Comment: Your answer is correct if i have 5*5 correct mapping of 25 records. Can you give the solution that how should I identify a mapping of 100 userid* 100productids who have given review score from so many rows.

Comment: you are welcome, you know better what to do with _over 60 million records_ for performance

Comment: couldn't you write a where clause instead of _--here you can limit the products and users_ in the above code?